# merging sorted collection with map

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, containers

I have n (let's say three) sorted key-value collections. The easiest way to merge them is to use std::map. Simple. However, because there are sorted, worth considering is to iterate through one collection and insert pair from the second collection in proper place, not using map::insert, which always will have O(n log n). So it seems to me that best for this situation will be using std::list with std::pair. I have also considered using std::vector with some maping keys on indexes and merging collections using new vector, however it will be more complicated.

Is this way of thinking have sense? Or is there any efficient way to use map in such task.

Thank You.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
{{60: 1},    {{75: 4},     {{100: 3}, 
 {70: 5},     {80: 2},      {120: 9},
 {80: 4}      {85: 4}}      {140: 7}}
 {90: 9}}
```

If it will help, general pattern for input is:

```
{{offset: random0}, 
 {offset + 1 * k: random1}, 
 {offset + 2 * k: random2}, 
 {offset + 3 * k: random3}, 
 {offset + 4 * k: random4}, ... }
```

and `{offset: random0}` means that for every element from range `<offset, offset + 1 * k)` value equals `random0`.

Output should be:

```
{{60: 1},
 {70: 5},
 {75: 9},  //{70: 5} + {75: 4}
 {80: 6},  //{80: 4} + {80: 2}
 {85: 8},  //{80: 4} + {85: 4}
 {90: 9},
 {100: 3},
 {120: 9},
 {140: 7}}
```

Finally, I consider using vector:

```
int upper_bound = 200;
vector<unsigned int> v(upper_bound, 0);
```

Then iterate through every map, and increment proper element in the vector. If key exceed bound, I will simple resize vector. Then I will reduce vector from elements which equal 0.

Comment: Use [std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), Luke!

Comment: std::merge doesn't update destination value when keys are equal, however std::accumulate seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates during merge ?

Comment: Duplicated keys seem to be merged, but why are `70` and `75` merged? Don't get it...

Comment: Traversing through and inserting into a map is almost as efficient as a list, so I'd just measure both variants and if the list version is not significantly faster, I'd stick to the map.

Comment: Sorry guys, problem is much more complicated. {offset: random0} means that for every element from range <offset, offset + 1 * k) value equals random0. {70: 5} really means {70:5}, {71:5}, {72:5} .. {79:5} and {75: 4} means {75:4} ...  {79:4}

Comment: @galvanize: Have you remarked that order of merge may change result ? As the range `90-100` has value `9` but if you merge 2nd and 3rd list first, the range becomes of value `9 + 4` (from `85-100`).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `map` providing you own `Compare` class when you declare it (third parameter of the template definition). Then you can freely use the `range insert` and read back your ordered elements using the proper iterators (you know, the methods `begin`, `end`).

The `map`'s internal representation is implicitly ordered by contract, so you don't have to care about how you insert your elements, instead you should provide a valid function to compare them.

Indeed, your collections are sorted, but I guess they are not reciprocally sorted (I mean, the collection `C1` contains elements that are spread all around within the collection `C2`, no guarantees that they will be placed contiguosly), is it?.